# Windows Forms vs Silverlight Forms

Tags: winforms, silverlight

Might be a pretty simple question but I was just wondering is there really a difference in Windows Forms vs. Silverlight Forms?

From what I know Windows Forms are basic day-to-day application forms and Silverlight is much more 'graphical' and appealing? Can someone elaborate more about this?

I was thinking of making a simple program for displaying stuff with a nice look and feel to it with animations and all and is using Silverlight a good choice?

Comment: Silverlight Forms? Are you referring to WPF? (Windows Presentation Foundation) Forms? The latter is intended to replace the former for all (.NET) applications. The only reasons I can think of for electing to continue to use Windows Forms, is if you need to build for older than .NET 3.0, or if you have libraries that require WinForms (i.e. nobody has created a WPF version). Other than that, it works fine - regardless of how many graphic effects you need.

Comment: @Digital_Utopia Thanks for that and yes WPF might be the correct term

Comment: Silverlight is hosted in a webpage. WinForms (and WPF) are desktop programes.

Comment: Silvelight can also be installed on the client as "Out Of Browser" (OOB).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WPF and Win Forms are similar - however WPF uses xaml for the UI. 
If you're wanting something a bit more "graphical" i would go with WPF as there is more flexibility with the UI.

WPF also contains some UI properties that Win Forms lacks - such as opacity of controls. When you say Silverlight, you probably mean to say WPF - as in browser silverlight has security implications and cannot be used to carry out many of the tasks that can be achived with WPF. (Modifying file systems without a dialog etc...)

Comment: Thanks. Seems like WPF is what I might use.

Comment: No problem, yep i would go for WPF too.